# Async call within if-condition

Tags: node.js, if-statement, asynchronous

I wonder what is the correct way to handle async call within if condition. For example I want to fix the following code.

```
if(criterium2){
    function1(value, function(error, result){
    })
    }
else {
    function2(value, function(error, result){
    })
    }
```

What is the best way to handle async call within if.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "fix"? This looks like a plain old callback hell. If you want to make the code more readable and maintainable use Promises instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Promises. If there's an async version of those functions, it'd be

```
var promise;

if(criterion) {
  promise = function1Async(value);
} 
else {
  promise = function2Async(value);
}

promise.then(function(resolvedResult) {
  // handle result
});
```

If there isn't an async version and they are node style functions, you can promisify them with the promise library of your choice.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    promise,
    function1Async = Promise.promisify(function1),
    function2Async = Promise.promisify(function2);

if(criterion) {
  promise = function1Async(value);
} 
else {
  promise = function2Async(value);
}

promise.then(function(resolvedResult) {
  // handle result
});
```